# How to get rid of 'summarise()` has grouped output by 'Condition'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.'

Tags: percentage, summarize

my goal was to calculate the percentage by the two variables 'Condition' and 'Category', following the codes below in which 'Combine1' is the data framework. With the codes below, the percentage was calculated based on the 'Condition' variable only but not both variables, which is because of this message'How to get rid of 'summarise()`has grouped output by 'Condition'. You can override using the`.groups` argument.' In this case, I add this line of code before the following code 'options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)'; however, the problem was not fixed. Does anyone have any idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Combine1 %>%  group_by(Condition, Category) %>% dplyr::summarize(n = n()) %>% mutate(pct = n/sum(n), lbl = scales::percent(pct))`

How to calculate the percentage by both grouping variables?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
group_by(Condition, Category, **groups= 'drop'**)
```

See the [r group_by function from dplyr 2](https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/r-group-by-function-from-dplyr-2/) documentation.